# How to split the row from mysql db passed through json_encode to display in separate textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I trying to split the result from a mysql statement output from one php page to another page containing javascript.
I tried below method but something is missing in my code :-(

The result I am looking forward is to get the values in each column from the selected row in mySQL table to populate into #eventTitle, #eventDescription and so on....

Please find my code below

lookup_event.php

```
<?php
$eid = $_POST['eid']
include '/include/db_connect.php';
$sql="SELECT title, description, start, end FROM evenement where id=".$eid;
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $sessions[] = $row;
     }

     echo json_encode($sessions);
     die();
     ?>
```

script in cal.php

```
eid = event.id;
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'lookup_event.php',
data: eid,
success: function (sessions) {
$('#eventTitle').val(sessions["title"]);
$('#eventDescription').val(sessions["description"]);
}
});
```

Comment: You can send your parameter as  `data:{eid:eid},`

Comment: @ Saty : Thanks, I could send the values to php without any issues and tried adding an alert to check the output. Its coming all in one line which I am trying to split and take values into each textboxes in my web page.

Comment: @ ImClarky, that was my typo. Updating now. However instead of having the result into #eventTitle, for temporarily, I tried to get the output into an alert box. The result is returned as 'undefined'..

Comment: To avoid sql inject, you should change $eid to intval($eid)  or use mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue. Thanks everyone for your support.

This is how now my files look like. However your comments for any modifications on below code are most welcome. Thanks once again.

```
lookup_event.php
<?php
include '/include/db_connect.php';
$eid = $_POST['eid'];
$sql = "SELECT title, description, start, end FROM evenement where id=" . intval($eid);
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result) {
  $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  }

echo json_encode($array);
die();
?>
```

cal.php

```
eid = event.id;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'lookup_event.php',
    data: {eid:eid},
    success: function (event) {
        var event = JSON.parse(event);
        $('#eventTitle').val(event.title);
        $('#eventStart').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#eventEnd').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#eventDescription').val(event.description);
        $('#myModal').modal();
    }
});
```

Comment: When `$result` is `false`, the `$array` variable will not be initialized. So, initialize the $array var before condition, like `$array = []`;

Answer (score 1):

Its coming as a string because its json. You first need to parse it.

script in cal.php

```
eid = event.id;
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'lookup_event.php',
data: eid,
  success: function (sessions) {
    var sessions = JSON.parse(sessions);

    $('#eventTitle').val(sessions["title"];
    $('#eventDescription').val(sessions["description"];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to start using PDO: http://php.net/pdo

And statement+binds to automatically escape SQL injections.

```
<?php
// ... include PDO connection ($conn)

$eid = (int) $_POST['eid'];

$sql = "SELECT title, description, start, end FROM evenement WHERE id = :id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('id', $eid);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'lookup_event.php',
    data: { eid: eid },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (event) {
        // with dataType specified dont need parse
    }
});
```